# Is there a way to Time Delay a Constraint (Like Slow Parent)

Tags: animation, objects

I have a large number of objects, let's say Cube.001 to Cube.100.

I want to be able to rotate Cube.001 on the z-axis and have all the other Cubes rotate with a slight delay starting with Cube.002 and then Cube.003 etc. (much like how slow parenting works).

I've been able to iterate and child/parent all the cubes with python and enable Slow Parent, problem is when I rotate Cube.001 all the Cubes transform their location, which I don't want.

Basically I need something like the 'Copy Rotation' Constraint, but with a Slow Parent like effect. Are their any simple ways of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The [Animation Nodes plugin](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes) can be used to generate objects and it has a [Delay Falloff](http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/falloff/delay_falloff.html) node which can transform them in sequence.

[This series](https://youtu.be/GF5krw0Z8QU?t=281) on youtube has an example.

Example based on link above:

- Line Mesh is used to generate the locations
- Object Instancer generates the cubes
- Replicate Matrix generates transform matrices from the positions
- Offset Matrix rotates each item, the delay falloff does them in sequence

[image: Example Node Layout]

Comment: Could you add some local details to your answer describing how this helps solve the issue? While reference links are encouraged, they should not be the only source of information of your post. As it stands this is a link only answer, and if the links go down your answer becomes empty.