# How to achieve this rigging-animation effect?

Tags: animation, rigging

Is there a way to achieve a similar effect in Blender: https://youtu.be/g532sTE1bEk?t=2038 ?

So when we move the head of the dragon the rest of the body moves smoothly, looks like some sort of inversed kinematics but it's different...

Answer (score 0):

On a quick glance there might be a small chance that this is what you need:

[Is there a way to Time Delay a Constraint (Like Slow Parent)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107383/is-there-a-way-to-time-delay-a-constraint-like-slow-parent)